References for orbifold curves
I am looking for a good reference (if there is any) for the theory of orbifold curves from the perspective of stacks. By an orbifold curve I mean something like a $1$-dimensional irreducible Deligne-Mumford stack $\mathcal{X}$ with generically trivial stabilizers. Mostly, I am interested in their categories of coherent sheaves (derived and abelian).
In spite of the fact that these objects are fairly concrete, I haven't seen too many references in the literature that collect results about them and I'd really appreciate a citeable reference to avoid having to reprove things that are probably well-known.

The answer to your question is that there is no good reference.
I am finishing up my PhD thesis on moduli of sheaves on stacky curves. If you want I can send you some drafts, that will hopefully be good citeable references in the future.

Dear Lisanne, Thanks for the offer. It would, of course, be appreciated. You can find my email on my personal page linked in my profile. Thanks in advance.

John Voight and I have a chapter in our book which collects proofs of several "well known" facts about stacky curves (e.g., the formula for the canonical divisor).
https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.04657
There we mostly only addressed facts that we needed for the rest of the book. In particular, we only work over fields. In a different paper with Ellenberg and Satriano, we needed to work with "stacky Spec Z"'s, and added some additional facts to our appendix.
https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.11340
